# Does Auth0 provide a way to export a user database?

Tags: auth0

Auth0 looks like a very promising user management solution, but I'm curious if it allows you to export a user database.

This is an important feature because:

1. I'd like to make my own backups. (Not so much because I'm worried Auth0 might lose my data. But what if there's a bug in my code or my Auth0 keys are compromised?)
2. I might want to switch user management providers someday.

From [Documentation > Importing Users to Auth0](https://auth0.com/docs/migrating), I see there's a way to import users (on-demand when you can obtain their passwords anyway). And I can see they use bcrypt for password hashing (at least by default). But I don't see any mention of *exporting users*.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Auth0 Management API allows you to export your data. Additionally, we have a tool that will help you both import and export users: https://auth0.com/docs/extensions/user-import-export

For the official policy see this document: https://auth0.com/docs/policies/data-export

Comment: Just to clarify, there's no "bulk export" feature yet but it's possible to download all users through the API: https://auth0.com/docs/api/v2#!/Users/get_users. Password hashes aren't exposed in that endpoint.

Comment: You can get the export with password hashes, you just have to a) have full support for at least a month and b) ask for them to do it.  Have to say that seems pretty fair to me and is definitely one of the things which makes it okay to use Auth0.  I've provided an answer below which explains this.

Comment: Depending on the data set you are after, Auth0 now supports exporting of users using their jobs API: https://auth0.com/docs/users/guides/bulk-user-exports

Answer (score 4):

Auth0 does not currently provide the facility to directly export password hashes.  Not on their API and not by downloading from their web interface.  Probably they never will provide this doing so would somewhat reduce security since an attacker with access to your Auth0 account could then attempt to brute force  all of the user's accounts rather than just the active ones.

To get a more or less compuete export of user data there are three possible ways, all of which require activity in advance.

1. Request a full export from support - currently you have to be already signed up for support at at least developer level for at least a month (see the document [Moving out of Auth0](https://auth0.com/docs/support/removing-auth0-exporting-data))
2. Do a gradual move out by creating a new, local password hash each time the user logs in. - you will have to wait for all your users to have logged in once.  This is the inverse of the [procedure for migrating in to Auth0](https://auth0.com/docs/connections/database/migrating).  N.B. this will mean you miss users who never log in during your migration period.
3. Create and store a password hash yourself using [Auth0s custom database connection](https://auth0.com/docs/connections/database/custom-db) for use whenever your user logs in.  If you already have users in Auth0 you can combine this with method 2. to migrate those users into your custom database.

The answer from Nathan Totten here covers how to get the rest of your user data, though Auth0 support should be able to provide you with an export including all of that.